# Set default screen position for Emacs GUI app

Tags: macos, emacs

I'm using the GUI version of Emacs installed using Homebrew-Cask. I launch it by searching into Spotlight, which as I understand is equivalent to opening it from the **Applications** directory.

App launches fine, but the window (or "frame", in Emacs lingo) always opens up on the upper left corner of the screen. I personally prefer everything to be right in the centre of the screen. Hence, every time I open Emacs, I have to manually drag the window to the center.

Is there a way to set the default position of the window to the centre of the screen so that I don't have to drag it every time I open Emacs?